# Unconstrained action in Yang-Mills theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, locality

Is there any gauge in which Yang-Mills theory (4d, non-SUSY) can be written as a local action containing only the propagating modes?

Comment: If there is one, it will not be explicitly Lorentz invariant, so please specify what you mean by "local". Would you allow a field which couples only with space-derivatives and no time derivatives? How about just one space derivative, does that count as local? Would you allow a straight-up Lagrange-multiplier field which has no derivatives?

Answer (score 2):

1. The usual definition of a *local action* forbids the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}(x)$ to contain inverse differential operators (=integration operators) like  $\partial_\mu^{-1}$, which is a non-local operation.

   If OP requires the action to be on manifestly local form in the above sense, then the answer is *No,* to the best of my knowledge.
2. On the other hand, if one does not require a manifestly local form, then it is possible to  write the gauge-fixed Yang-Mills action in $d\geq 2$ spacetime dimensions using propagating transversal gauge potentials only.

   Consider the light-cone formulation (which implies that evolution/propagation is wrt. the [light-cone coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone_coordinates) $x^+$ as opposed to $x^0\equiv t$) in the [light-cone gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone_gauge) $A^+=0$.

   Then the gauge potential $A^{-}$ becomes a non-propagating [auxiliary field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_field), which can be integrated out. This yields a Lagrangian density that only contains $d-2$ propagating transversal fields, but with inverse powers of $\partial_-$, and hence non-local.

   See e.g. Warren Siegel, *Fields,* p. 210, [arXiv:hep-th/9912205](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912205), for further details.